# Simple code-golf programming language written in Python

Tags: python, interpreter, language-design

I've written a "simple" interpreter for a programming language in Python, called Tellurium (named after the element of the same name). So far, it's working pretty well, but there are some things I'd like to fix/remove.

Tellurium is a tape-based language, so it uses a tape to store data.

```
import string, sys, random, time, codecs

tape = [0] * 25500
funcs = {}
variables = {}
readingStr = False
readingLoopAmount = False
readingLoopCode = False
readingRand = False
readingRand2 = False
readingFName = False
readingFCode = False
readingName = False
readingVName = False
readingFileName = False
readingVText = False
readingVName2 = False
appendToFront = False
appendToBack = False
loopInf = False
loopRand = False
string = False
isChar = False
fileName = []
vName = []
vText = []
vName2 = []
tempText = []
tempName = []
fName = []
fCode = []
text = []
rand = []
rand2 = []
loopCode = []
loopAmount = []
selected = 0

def prompt():
    cmd = input("> ")
    return cmd

def read(cmd):
    if "!K" in cmd:
        cmd = cmd.replace("!K", "1000")

    if "!H" in cmd:
        cmd = cmd.replace("!H", "100")

    commands = len(cmd)
    tokens = list(cmd)
    for i in range(0, commands):
        parse(tokens[i])

def parse(cmd):
    # Sorry for all these globals...
    global tape
    global funcs
    global variables
    global readingStr
    global readingFileName
    global readingLoopAmount
    global readingLoopCode
    global readingRand
    global readingRand2
    global readingFName
    global readingFCode
    global readingName
    global readingVName
    global readingVText
    global readingVName2
    global appendToFront
    global appendToBack
    global loopInf
    global loopRand
    global vName, vText, vName2
    global fileName
    global string
    global isChar
    global tempName
    global tempText
    global fName
    global fCode
    global text
    global rand
    global rand2
    global loopCode
    global loopAmount
    global selected

    if readingFileName == True:
        if cmd == "]":
            readingFileName = False
            f = open(''.join(fileName), 'r')
            code = f.read()
            f.close()
            read(code)
            fileName = []

        else:
            fileName.append(cmd)


    elif readingVName2 == True:
        if cmd == ".":
            readingVName2 = False
            tape[selected] = variables[''.join(vName2)]
            vName2 = []

        else:
            vName2.append(cmd)

    elif readingVName == True:
        if cmd == "|":
            readingVText = True
            readingVName = False

        else:
            vName.append(cmd)

    elif readingVText == True:
        if cmd == "]":
            readingVText = False
            name = ''.join(vName)
            val = ''.join(vText)
            variables[name] = val
            vName = []
            vText = []

        else:
            vText.append(cmd)

    elif readingName == True:
        if cmd == ".":
            readingName = False
            name = ''.join(tempName)
            read(funcs[name])
            tempName = []

        else:
            tempName.append(cmd)

    elif readingFName == True:
        if cmd == "|":
            readingFName = False
            readingFCode = True

        else:
            fName.append(cmd)

    elif readingFCode == True:
        if cmd == "`":
            readingFCode = False
            name = ''.join(fName)
            code = ''.join(fCode)
            funcs[name] = code
            fName = []
            fCode = []

        else:
            fCode.append(cmd)

    elif readingRand == True:
        if cmd == "|":
            readingRand = False

        else:
            rand.append(cmd)

    elif readingRand2 == True:
        if cmd == "|":
            readingRand2 = False

        else:
            rand2.append(cmd)

    elif string == True:
        if appendToFront == True:
            if cmd == "~":
                tape[selected] = str(tape[selected]) + ''.join(tempText)
                tempText = []
                appendToFront = False

            elif cmd == "$":
                tape[selected] = str(tape[selected]) + str(tape[selected-1])
                appendToFront = False
                tempText = []

            else:
                tempText.append(cmd)

        elif appendToBack == True:
            if cmd == "~":
                tape[selected] = ''.join(tempText) + str(tape[selected])
                tempText = []
                appendToBack = False

            elif cmd == "$":
                tape[selected] = str(tape[selected-1]) + str(tape[selected])
                appendToFront = False
                tempText = []

            else:
                tempText.append(cmd)

        elif cmd == "r":
            tape[selected] = tape[selected].reverse()

        elif cmd == "u":
            tape[selected] = tape[selected].upper()

        elif cmd == "l":
            tape[selected] = tape[selected].lower()

        elif cmd == "a":
            appendToFront = True

        elif cmd == "b":
            appendToBack = True

        elif cmd == ".":
            string = False

    elif readingLoopAmount == True:
        if cmd == "|":
            readingLoopAmount = False
            readingLoopCode = True

        elif cmd == "i":
            loopInf = True

        elif cmd == "r":
            loopRand = True

        else:
            loopAmount.append(cmd)

    elif readingLoopCode == True:
        if cmd == "]":
            readingLoopCode = False
            if loopInf == True:
                while 1:
                    read(loopCode)

            if loopRand == True:
                if rand and rand2 == []:
                    for i in range(0, random.randint(0, 100)):
                        read(loopCode)

                else:
                    if rand2 == []:
                        for i in range(0, random.randint(0, int(''.join(rand)))):
                            read(loopCode)

                    elif rand == []:
                        for i in range(0, random.randint(int(''.join(rand2)), 100)):
                            read(loopCode)

                    else:
                        for i in range(0, random.randint(int(''.join(rand2)), int(''.join(rand)))):
                            read(loopCode)

            else:
                for i in range(0, int(''.join(loopAmount))):
                    read(loopCode)

            loopCode = []
            loopAmount = []

        else:
            loopCode.append(cmd)

    elif readingStr == True:
        if cmd == "~":
            readingStr = False
            text = ''.join(text).replace("µ", "")
            tape[selected] = text
            text = []

        else:
            text.append(cmd)

    elif cmd == "+":
        tape[selected] += 1

    elif cmd == "-":
        tape[selected] -= 1

    elif cmd == ">":
        selected += 1

    elif cmd == "<":
        selected -= 1

    elif cmd == "*":
        print(selected)

    elif cmd == "^":
        print(tape[selected])

    elif cmd == "!":
        if isinstance(tape[selected], str):
            print(tape[selected])
        else:
            print(chr(tape[selected]))

    elif cmd == "%":
        tape[selected] = ord(tape[selected])

    elif cmd == "#":
        tape[selected] = 0

    elif cmd == "$":
        selected = 0

    elif cmd == "/":
        tape[selected] += 10

    elif cmd == "\\":
        tape[selected] -= 10

    elif cmd == "{":
        selected += 10

    elif cmd == "}":
        selected -= 10

    elif cmd == '"':
        tape[selected] += 100

    elif cmd == "'":
        tape[selected] -= 100

    elif cmd == "-":
        selected += 100

    elif cmd == "_":
        selected -= 100

    elif cmd == "i":
        tape[selected] = input(">> ")

    elif cmd == "n":
        tape[selected] = int(tape[selected])

    elif cmd == "a":
        tape[selected] = int(tape[selected]) + int(tape[selected+1])

    elif cmd == "s":
        tape[selected] = int(tape[selected]) - int(tape[selected+1])

    elif cmd == "m":
        tape[selected] = int(tape[selected]) * int(tape[selected+1])

    elif cmd == "d":
        tape[selected] = int(tape[selected]) / int(tape[selected+1])

    elif cmd == "(":
        readingNum = True

    elif cmd == "z":
        tape[selected] = tape[selected+1]

    elif cmd == "x":
        tape[selected] = tape[selected-1]

    elif cmd == "µ":
        readingStr = True

    elif cmd == "[":
        readingLoopAmount = True

    elif cmd == "p":
        return

    elif cmd == ".":
        exit

    elif cmd == "&":
        string = True

    elif cmd == "→":
        if rand != []:
            rand = []

        readingRand = True

    elif cmd == "←":
        if rand2 != []:
            rand2 = []

        readingRand2 = True

    elif cmd == "t":
        tape[selected] = str(time.ctime())

    elif cmd == "¨":
        time.sleep(1)

    elif cmd == "r":
        tape[selected] = codecs.encode(str(tape[selected]), 'rot_13')

    elif cmd == "n":
        tape[selected] = int(tape[selected])

    elif cmd == "@":
        readingFName = True

    elif cmd == "=":
        readingName = True

    elif cmd == "¤":
        readingVName = True

    elif cmd == ";":
        readingVName2 = True

    elif cmd == "0":
        readingFileName = True

    elif cmd == "f":
        tape[selected] = float(tape[selected])

while 1:
    read(prompt())
```

### Example programs

- **Hello, world!** - `µHello, world!~^`

  Explanation: everything after `µ` and before `~` will be read and stored in the tape's currently selected cell. `^` outputs whatever is in the selected cell, which in the program is `Hello, world!`.
- **Cat program** - `i^`

  Explanation: `i` reads input and stores it in the selected cell. `^` outputs whatever is in the cell.
- **Navigating cells** - `+>++>+++<<^>^>^`

  Explanation: `+` adds one to the selected cell's value. `>` goes forward one cell in the tape. `<` goes back, and `^` outputs whatever is in the selected cell. So, the output is `123`, separated by newlines.
- **Math (addition)** - `+>+<a^`

  Explanation: If you read the above example, you'll know what the `+`, `>` and `<` commands do. The `a` command is the addition command. It takes the values of the selected cell and the next one up, and adds them together. The result is stored in the selected cell. The other math commands are `s` (subtraction), `m` (multiplication) and `d` (division).
- **Loop** - `[5|^]`

  Explanation: The syntax of a for loop in Tellurium is `[times|code]`. So, this outputs the selected cell's value 5 times.
- **Clock** - `[i|t^¨]`

  Explanation: `t` stores the current time and date in the selected cell. `¨` waits one second before continuing the code. `i` makes a loop run forever. The code will keep printing the current time and date every second.
- **Countdown** - `/[10|-^¨]`

  Explanation: `/` adds ten to the selected cell's value. The loop after that runs the code `-^¨` ten times. `-` subtracts one from the cell's value.`
- **Functions** - `@a|^^^^]`

  Explanation: this program creates a function called `a`, which outputs the selected cell's value four times.
- **Calling functions** - `=a.`

  Explanation: this calls a function called `a`. (The `.` is needed, otherwise it won't work)
- **Appending to strings** - `µHello,`&aworld!~.^`

  Explanation: this sets the value of the selected cell to `Hello,`. `&` starts string manipulation mode. While in string mode, you can use the `a` command to append to the end of a string. In this example, it appends `world!` to the end of the selected cell`.`.` exits string manipulation mode.

---

The reason I posted this here is because the code is messy and quite unreadable. I'm looking for some tips to clean it up, remove the unneeded things, etc. Also, I'd like to remove the big list of variables and global statements, if possible. They're limiting the flexibility of the language. For example, I can't implement conditional statements until I've removed the globals. I've tried, but it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 7):

Seeing as it's a long post, I'll just see where I can get, starting now.

First, `prompt`:

```
def prompt():
    cmd = input("> ")
    return cmd
```

You don't need the intermediate variable. Just write this:

```
def prompt():
    return input("> ")
```

Also, you only use it once, so why not use `input("> ")` instead of `prompt()`?.

Next, `read`:

```
def read(cmd):
    if "!K" in cmd:
        cmd = cmd.replace("!K", "1000")

    if "!H" in cmd:
        cmd = cmd.replace("!H", "100")

    commands = len(cmd)
    tokens = list(cmd)
    for i in range(0, commands):
        parse(tokens[i])
```

The `if` checks can be gone, because otherwise `.replace` is just a no-op. (It might matter for efficiency, perhaps!). That leaves us with

```
def read(cmd):
    cmd = cmd.replace("!K", "1000")
    cmd = cmd.replace("!H", "100")

    commands = len(cmd)
    tokens = list(cmd)
    for i in range(0, commands):
        parse(tokens[i])
```

Also, looping over a string gives us a list of characters. Using that, we get

```
def read(cmd):
    if isinstance(cmd, str):
        cmd = cmd.replace("!K", "1000")
        cmd = cmd.replace("!H", "100")

    for token in cmd:
        parse(token)
```

Which reads a bit saner. The `isinstance` is needed, because `cmd` is sometimes a list, and that does not have a `replace` method. (Alternatively, make sure `read` is always called with a `str`).

## Binary int operations.

Browsing down further, I see the following interesting piece of code:

```
elif cmd == "a":
    tape[selected] = int(tape[selected]) + int(tape[selected+1])

elif cmd == "s":
    tape[selected] = int(tape[selected]) - int(tape[selected+1])

elif cmd == "m":
    tape[selected] = int(tape[selected]) * int(tape[selected+1])

elif cmd == "d":
    tape[selected] = int(tape[selected]) / int(tape[selected+1])
```

See the repetition? This is easily fixable, add the following to the top of your module:

```
import operator

INT_BINOPS = {
    "a": operator.add,
    "s": operator.sub,
    "m": operator.mul,
    "d": operator.truediv,  # Maybe you meant floordiv?
}
```

and replace the `elif` change with

```
elif cmd in INT_BINOPS:
    op = INT_BINOPS[cmd]
    tape[selected] = op(int(tape[selected]), int(tape[selected + 1]))
```

## in-place unary operations

Next, I moved the cases for `/`, `\`, `"`, `'`, `n`, `%` closer together to bring out the similarity:

```
elif cmd == "/":
    tape[selected] += 10

elif cmd == "\\":
    tape[selected] -= 10

elif cmd == '"':
    tape[selected] += 100

elif cmd == "'":
    tape[selected] -= 100

elif cmd == "n":
    tape[selected] = int(tape[selected])

elif cmd == "%":
    tape[selected] = ord(tape[selected])
```

Reading carefully, all have the form

```
tape[selected] = f(tape[selected])
```

for proper functions `f`. Let's apply the same trick. Using `lambda` because

```
import functools
INPLACE_UNARYOPS = {
    "+": functools.partial(operator.add, 1),
    "-": functools.partial(operator.add, -1),  # can't use .sub here
    "/": functools.partial(operator.add, 10),
    "\\": functools.partial(operator.add, -10),  # can't use .sub here
    '"': functools.partial(operator.add, 100),
    "'": functools.partial(operator.add, -100),  # can't use .sub here
    "n": int,
    "%": ord,
}
```

and then in the `elif` chain use

```
elif cmd in INPLACE_UNARYOPS:
    op = INPLACE_UNARYOPS[cmd]
    tape[selected] = op(tape[selected])
```

(funnily enough, you actually have "n" twice, I just removed one of them).

Furthermore, I also added `"r"` and `"f"` to the dictionary as follows (because I missed those):

```
    "r": lambda v: codecs.encode(str(v), 'rot_13'),
    "f": float,
```

## Assignment from nowhere

There are also `"t"`, `"i"` and `"#"` which look alike. They get the same treatment as before. At the top:

```
FUNCS = {
    "t": lambda: str(time.ctime()),
    "#": lambda: 0,
    "i": lambda: input(">> "),
}
```

And in the `if`-chain:

```
elif cmd in FUNCS:
    tape[selected] = FUNCS[cmd]()
```

## Uniform position logic

Again, make things simple. Move similar things together:

```
elif cmd == "$":
    selected = 0

elif cmd == ">":
    selected += 1

elif cmd == "<":
    selected -= 1

elif cmd == "{":
    selected += 10

elif cmd == "}":
    selected -= 10

elif cmd == "-":
    selected += 100

elif cmd == "_":
    selected -= 100
```

You can probably expect the drill:

```
POSITION_ACTIONS = {
    "$": lambda _: 0,
    ">": functools.partial(operator.add, 1),
    "<": functools.partial(operator.add, -1),
    "{": functools.partial(operator.add, 10),
    "}": functools.partial(operator.add, -10),
    "-": functools.partial(operator.add, 100),
    "_": functools.partial(operator.add, -100),
}
```

And the handler:

```
elif cmd in POSITION_ACTIONS:
    selected = POSITION_ACTIONS[cmd](selected)
```

Make sure it is *later* than the value-actions, because you re-used "-" (bug?).

## Complex logic

Now, the above changes were fairly trivial (but beneficial!). You can probably handle some extra cases as well.

But there's also a bit of complex logic.

I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction, so bear with me for a while.

First, I'll rename `parse` to `_parse`, and define a function `parse` as follows:

```
def parse(token):
    return _parse(token)
```

Please convince yourself that this changes nothing.

Next, I'm going to change that again to

```
parser_stack = [_parse]
def parse(token):
    parser_stack[-1](token)
```

Again, this should not change anything.

And now I'll show you why: we're going to replace the `readFileName` case. First we add the function

```
def read_filename(cmd):
    global fileName
    if cmd == "]":
        parser_stack.pop()
        f = open(''.join(fileName), 'r')
        code = f.read()
        f.close()
        read(code)
        fileName = []
    else:
        fileName.append(cmd)
```

(Which is copy-pasted from the `if readingFileName` case, with some modifications).

Then, we're going to replace

```
elif cmd == "0":
    readingFileName = True
```

with

```
elif cmd == "0":
    parser_stack.append(read_filename)
```

and we can remove the `if readingFileName:` case, because that's now handled by another parser.

I've given some other stuff the same handling.

## Continue from here.

```
import string, sys, random, time, codecs

import functools
import operator

INT_BINOPS = {
    "a": operator.add,
    "s": operator.sub,
    "m": operator.mul,
    "d": operator.truediv,
}

INPLACE_UNARYOPS = {
    "+": functools.partial(operator.add, 1),
    "-": functools.partial(operator.add, -1),
    "/": functools.partial(operator.add, 10),
    "\\": functools.partial(operator.add, -10),  # can't use .sub here
    '"': functools.partial(operator.add, 100),
    "'": functools.partial(operator.add, -100),
    "n": int,
    "f": float,
    "%": ord,
    "r": lambda v: codecs.encode(str(v), 'rot_13'),
}

FUNCS = {
    "t": lambda: str(time.ctime()),
    "#": lambda: 0,
    "i": lambda: input(">> "),
}

POSITION_ACTIONS = {
    "$": lambda _: 0,
    ">": functools.partial(operator.add, 1),
    "<": functools.partial(operator.add, -1),
    "{": functools.partial(operator.add, 10),
    "}": functools.partial(operator.add, -10),
    "-": functools.partial(operator.add, 100),
    "_": functools.partial(operator.add, -100),
}

tape = [0] * 25500
funcs = {}
variables = {}
readingStr = False
readingLoopAmount = False
readingLoopCode = False
readingRand = False
readingRand2 = False
readingFName = False
readingFCode = False
appendToFront = False
appendToBack = False
loopInf = False
loopRand = False
string = False
isChar = False
fileName = []
tempText = []
tempName = []
fName = []
fCode = []
text = []
rand = []
rand2 = []
loopCode = []
loopAmount = []
selected = 0

def read(cmd):
    if isinstance(cmd, str):
        cmd = cmd.replace("!K", "1000")
        cmd = cmd.replace("!H", "100")

    for token in cmd:
        parse(token)

def _parse(cmd):
    # Sorry for all these globals...
    global tape
    global funcs
    global variables
    global readingStr
    global readingLoopAmount
    global readingLoopCode
    global readingRand
    global readingRand2
    global readingFName
    global readingFCode
    global appendToFront
    global appendToBack
    global loopInf
    global loopRand
    global vName, vText
    global fileName
    global string
    global isChar
    global tempName
    global tempText
    global fName
    global fCode
    global text
    global rand
    global rand2
    global loopCode
    global loopAmount
    global selected

    if readingFName == True:
        if cmd == "|":
            readingFName = False
            readingFCode = True

        else:
            fName.append(cmd)

    elif readingFCode == True:
        if cmd == "`":
            readingFCode = False
            name = ''.join(fName)
            code = ''.join(fCode)
            funcs[name] = code
            fName = []
            fCode = []

        else:
            fCode.append(cmd)

    elif readingRand == True:
        if cmd == "|":
            readingRand = False

        else:
            rand.append(cmd)

    elif readingRand2 == True:
        if cmd == "|":
            readingRand2 = False

        else:
            rand2.append(cmd)

    elif string == True:
        if appendToFront == True:
            if cmd == "~":
                tape[selected] = str(tape[selected]) + ''.join(tempText)
                tempText = []
                appendToFront = False

            elif cmd == "$":
                tape[selected] = str(tape[selected]) + str(tape[selected-1])
                appendToFront = False
                tempText = []

            else:
                tempText.append(cmd)

        elif appendToBack == True:
            if cmd == "~":
                tape[selected] = ''.join(tempText) + str(tape[selected])
                tempText = []
                appendToBack = False

            elif cmd == "$":
                tape[selected] = str(tape[selected-1]) + str(tape[selected])
                appendToFront = False
                tempText = []

            else:
                tempText.append(cmd)

        elif cmd == "r":
            tape[selected] = tape[selected].reverse()

        elif cmd == "u":
            tape[selected] = tape[selected].upper()

        elif cmd == "l":
            tape[selected] = tape[selected].lower()

        elif cmd == "a":
            appendToFront = True

        elif cmd == "b":
            appendToBack = True

        elif cmd == ".":
            string = False

    elif readingLoopAmount == True:
        if cmd == "|":
            readingLoopAmount = False
            readingLoopCode = True

        elif cmd == "i":
            loopInf = True

        elif cmd == "r":
            loopRand = True

        else:
            loopAmount.append(cmd)

    elif readingLoopCode == True:
        if cmd == "]":
            readingLoopCode = False
            if loopInf == True:
                while 1:
                    read(loopCode)

            if loopRand == True:
                if rand and rand2 == []:
                    for i in range(0, random.randint(0, 100)):
                        read(loopCode)

                else:
                    if rand2 == []:
                        for i in range(0, random.randint(0, int(''.join(rand)))):
                            read(loopCode)

                    elif rand == []:
                        for i in range(0, random.randint(int(''.join(rand2)), 100)):
                            read(loopCode)

                    else:
                        for i in range(0, random.randint(int(''.join(rand2)), int(''.join(rand)))):
                            read(loopCode)

            else:
                for i in range(0, int(''.join(loopAmount))):
                    read(loopCode)

            loopCode = []
            loopAmount = []

        else:
            loopCode.append(cmd)

    elif readingStr == True:
        if cmd == "~":
            readingStr = False
            text = ''.join(text).replace("µ", "")
            tape[selected] = text
            text = []

        else:
            text.append(cmd)

    elif cmd == "*":
        print(selected)

    elif cmd == "^":
        print(tape[selected])

    elif cmd == "!":
        if isinstance(tape[selected], str):
            print(tape[selected])
        else:
            print(chr(tape[selected]))

    elif cmd in FUNCS:
        tape[selected] = FUNCS[cmd]()

    elif cmd in INPLACE_UNARYOPS:
        op = INPLACE_UNARYOPS[cmd]
        tape[selected] = op(tape[selected])

    elif cmd in INT_BINOPS:
        op = INT_BINOPS[cmd]
        tape[selected] = op(int(tape[selected]), int(tape[selected + 1]))

    elif cmd in POSITION_ACTIONS:
        selected = POSITION_ACTIONS[cmd](selected)

    elif cmd == "(":
        readingNum = True

    elif cmd == "z":
        tape[selected] = tape[selected+1]

    elif cmd == "x":
        tape[selected] = tape[selected-1]

    elif cmd == "µ":
        readingStr = True

    elif cmd == "[":
        readingLoopAmount = True

    elif cmd == "p":
        return

    elif cmd == ".":
        exit

    elif cmd == "&":
        string = True

    elif cmd == "→":
        if rand != []:
            rand = []

        readingRand = True

    elif cmd == "←":
        if rand2 != []:
            rand2 = []

        readingRand2 = True

    elif cmd == "¨":
        time.sleep(1)

    elif cmd == "@":
        readingFName = True

    elif cmd == "=":
        parser_stack.append(read_name)
    elif cmd == "¤":
        parser_stack.append(read_vname)
    elif cmd == ";":
        parser_stack.append(read_vname2)
    elif cmd == "0":
        parser_stack.append(read_filename)


parser_stack = [_parse]


def read_name(cmd):
    global tempName
    if cmd == ".":
        parser_stack.pop()
        name = ''.join(tempName)
        read(funcs[name])
        tempName = []
    else:
        tempName.append(cmd)


def read_vtext(cmd):
    global vName, vText
    if cmd == "]":
        parser_stack.pop()
        name = ''.join(vName)
        val = ''.join(vText)
        variables[name] = val
        vName = []
        vText = []
    else:
        vText.append(cmd)


def read_vname(cmd):
    if cmd == "|":
        parser_stack.pop()
        parser_stack.append(read_vtext)
    else:
        vName.append(cmd)


def read_vname2(cmd):
    global vName2
    if cmd == ".":
        parser_stack.pop()
        tape[selected] = variables[''.join(vName2)]
        vName2 = []

    else:
        vName2.append(cmd)



def read_filename(cmd):
    global fileName
    if cmd == "]":
        parser_stack.pop()
        f = open(''.join(fileName), 'r')
        code = f.read()
        f.close()
        read(code)
        fileName = []

    else:
        fileName.append(cmd)

def parse(token):
    return parser_stack[-1](token)

while 1:
    read(input("> "))
```

## Conclusion

I hope I have given you some ideas on how to improve the code even further. I hope it makes sense to you.

I have also ignored a lot of stuff for now (PEP8, globals, etc). If you want you can continue on the path I've shown for a while, and when you see nothing left where you have an idea for improvement, feel free to ask another question for the resulting code. Hopefully it'll be split up enough that you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: Just don't edit the code in the question (adding usage examples is good though! Thank you!)

Comment: @m654: I've updated the review with some more, but now I really need to stop tweaking it, because I also have other responsibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! The code looks much better now, and I'm pretty sure it works better as well.

Comment: I haven't fully tested it. I checked github, it could use automated tests so that you can be more confident in changing the code without breaking functionality.